# Installing ASP.Net 2.0 after IIS

Tags: iis, .net-2.0, installation

I just got a dedicated server from a hosting company, and for some reason, it didn't have IIS installed.
It did have .Net 2.0, though.

So I installed IIS, but now my ASP.net websites won't work.
I just get a 404, no event log entries, nothing...

I noticed in the redistributable package information that:
"To access the features of ASP.NET, IIS with the latest security updates must be installed prior to installing the .NET Framework"

I also can't uninstall .Net, it just won't let me...

Is there a way to reinstall .Net 2.0, or somehow do whatever it is it does to IIS to make it work?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

run from the command line

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

You may have to navigate to the folder it was installed.
Mine and the default is

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I wanted.
You rock. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have enabled the extensions for asp and aspx in IIS.  They are disabled by default.  I'd do this before you go about uninstall more components.

Answer (score 0):

same command you can run it from Visual Studio Command Prompt as well, then you don't need to navigate to above path

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty convenient in Windows 10.

In Control Panel, Windows features, check ASP.NET 3.5, and then just wait for the download and installation.

[image]